# What something fishy is going on in Vim with relative number?

Tags: vim, vi

In Vim, you can set relative numbers

```
:set relativenumber
```

You will see the numbers who are subtracting of counting from the line where your cursor is placed. But I don't like the 0 as cursor, so I did :set number

And tadaa, you see the number of the current line where your cursor is.

I set it in my vimrc.

```
set relativenumber
set number
```

But I noticed something wrong. When you opened a split window, you see that the number where your cursor is, have jumped back to 0 in the window. When you close the window, you see that the number is still 0 in another buffer.

I tried to fix this in my vimrc, to give the autocmmands when you doing something with windows or buffers:

```
set relativenumber
set number

autocmd BufWinEnter * set nu
autocmd BufDelete * set nu
autocmd BufCreate * set number
autocmd BufLeave * set number
autocmd BufWinEnter * set nu
autocmd WinEnter * set nu
```

But nothing of them worked so far. The cursor still jumps back to 0. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong there?

When I am in the window, and I set the number manually, it worked. But why can't I give it to an autocommand?

Comment: Please post the whole content of your vimrc and tell us where exactly it is on your system.

Comment: Please give exact steps to reproduce the problem, and describe it more clearly. For example, when you open a split window, you have two windows, and I do not know which one you mean by "the window."  If you are editing foo.txt and then `:sp bar.txt" then you can refer to the foo window and the bar window.

Comment: @romainl, my Vimrc counts more than 500 lines. So I guess I would flood you and everyone if I place my Vimrc here? But I noticed also this don't work properly on another systems.  My Vimrc is located in the PATH folder of my Windows, and other settings in my vimrc works properly.

Comment: @benjifisher, it is applicable on every window after :vsplit command. When you're close one window, the other window will have the line number 0, regardless which window you closed.

Comment: I still do not understand the problem.  When `'relativenumber'` is set, the line with the cursor on it is supposed to be numbered 0.  Please explain more clearly what you are seeing that is wrong.  Also, why do you try to set `'number'` as well as `'relativenumber'`?  If you set either one, then it will reset the other.

Comment: Which Vim version do you use? There were quite some patches until the new `:set nu nru` behavior was done.

Comment: @IngoKarkat: I use Gvim, version 7.4 on Windows 7.

Comment: @benjifisher see this example: http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/images/hybridnumber.png On the current line, the current number of line, the rest relative number. You can try it to set relativenumber, then try set nu. You see the result. My problem the current number jumped back to 0 (unsetted) when I split windows, or close windows.

Comment: SAME PROBLEM! When I set *:relativenumber* I am stuck with relative numers even after I do *:number*. I read something about upgrading to vim 7.4 I **have** vim 7.4!

Comment: Cannot reproduce this with vim 8+